# BeautifulSoup to CSV

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I have setup BeautifulSoup to find a specific class for two webpages.

I would like to know how to write each URL's result to a unique cell in one CSV?

Also is there a limit to the number of URLs I can read as I would like to expand this to about 200 URLs once I get this working.

The class is always the same and I don't need any formatting just the raw HTML in one cell per URL.

Thanks for any ideas.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
urls = ['https://www.ozbargain.com.au/','https://www.ozbargain.com.au/forum']
for u in urls:
    response = requests.get(u)
    data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
    soup.find('div', class_="block")
```

Comment: Your question is not clear and missing detailed information. what's the desired output? which class specifically as there's many classes holding the same name with different attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas` to work with tabular data: [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to create a table, and [`pd.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to save table as csv (might also check out the documentation, append mode for example).

Basically it.

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def func(urls):
    for url in urls:
        data = requests.get(url).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
        yield {
            "url": url, "raw_html": soup.find('div', class_="block")
        }


urls = ['https://www.ozbargain.com.au/','https://www.ozbargain.com.au/forum']

data = func(urls)
table = pd.DataFrame(data)
table.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```